# Using DOM inspector to find the ID of a button

Tags: ruby, dom, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to use the DOM inspector to find the ID of the "More" button at the bottom of [this page](http://www.quora.com/Startups/best_questions) that reveals more results.

I'm trying to do something like this example:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'svpply.com/editors_pick'

#count products
puts b.elements(:xpath => '//li[@data-class="Product"]').count
#=> 30

#Now click button
show_all = b.button(:id => "btn_all")
show_all.click
sleep 4

#count products again
puts b.elements(:xpath => '//li[@data-class="Product"]').count
#=>60
```

However, I'm unclear on how to search for that particular id within the DOM structure. Can someone also explain the difference between an attribute, element, id, and node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the DOM Inspector for the More button:

1. Open the DOM Inspector (Ctrl+Shift+I)
2. Click the [More] button that you want to inspect
3. On the right side of the DOM Inspector bar, click the [HTML] button
4. This should show the HTML for the page, which will include the details of the [More] control. You'll notice that the element is actually a DIV not a button. As well that the ID is in the form "_more".

--> This should show the HTML for the page, which will show the details of the [More] control. You'll notice that the element is actually a DIV not a button. As well that the ID is in the form "_more".

So to do your example with the Quora page, you would do something like:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

class QuoraPage
    def initialize(browser)
        @browser = browser
    end

    def goto()
        @browser.goto 'http://www.quora.com/Startups/best_questions'
        wait_questions_loaded
    end

    def click_more()
        @browser.div(:id, /_more/).click
        wait_questions_loaded
    end

    def questions_count()
        @browser.links(:class, 'question_link').count{ |x| x.visible? }
    end

    def wait_questions_loaded()
        begin
            questions_start_count = questions_count()
            sleep(2)
        end while questions_start_count != questions_count()
    end 
end

page = QuoraPage.new(Watir::Browser.new :chrome)
page.goto
puts page.questions_count
page.click_more
puts page.questions_count
```

Note that I had to put the sleeps in otherwise webdriver hangs like anonygoose mentioned. I tried different wait_untils, but did not manage to find something that worked (other than sleep which is not very robust).

Regarding your question about nodes, elements, etc. I think you are best to look at http://www.w3schools.com/dom/default.asp.

Comment: Hi, thanks this is really helpful. I'm wondering - did you get it to work with the sleeps? My request timed out and I tried upping the sleeps, but I'm not sure if this is actually variable from machine to machine.

Comment: Odd. The script ran fine yesterday. I too am now getting problems with the script hanging. I wonder if it is an issue with the size of the page.

Comment: I am pretty sure the timeouts are due to working with such a large page. The only solution to that is to use Chrome (usually works) or switch to Watir (seems to always work). I also updated the solution to include a wait method that is more robust than just sleeping.

Comment: Is there a way for me to link in all the defs from the Watir::Browser library even though I'm using the QuoraPage class in your example? I'd  like to have element_by_xpath, div, and text, for example.

Comment: Yes, the `@browser` in the QuoraPage class is a `Watir::Browser` object. You can use the `@browser` object just like you would any other `Watir::Browser` object (eg `@browser.text_field(:id, 'id').set('value')`). In this example, the class was created to make it easier to pass the Watir::Browser object between methods. However, there are plenty of benefits of using a page object pattern (see [here](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/wiki/Page-Objects) as a starting point).

Answer (score 1):

To press the button on svpply you can use simply

```
b.button(:text => "Show All").click
```

Counting all the products that appear on the page could potentially be done with

```
b.lis(:class => "grab large").count
```

This is all for the svpply site.  I can't get quora to automate at all, it just stalls my watir-webdriver indefinitely.

You'll also want to wait before you have watir count the products.  This can be done with:

```
b.wait_until{b.lis(:class => "grab large").count > 30}
```